# Python: kivy DragBehaviour on release

Tags: python, kivy

I have an app built with Kivy where I have objects possible to be dragged with the help of Kivy's DragBehavior.

What I want to do is - when someone drags an object to a certain area of the screen, but doesn't match it exactly on the pixel - I want to set - within a certain range - the position to the exact point they tried to place it on. For example:

```
if 100 < self.center[0] < 300 and 400 < self.center[1] < 600:
    self.x = 90
    self.y = 850
```

I would like this check to only occur when the object is released (so mouse release) but I can't seem to find how to do this.

Comment: Hi, please read [what would be good way to ask a question](http://stackoverflow.com/help), and [how to create minimal example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)  in order to help people understand - and possibly then - help You.

Comment: Oh I see, well what I'm really only trying to find out is if its possible to get some sort of on_drag_release when using DragBehaviour in kivy

Comment: I'd check if `on_touch_up(touch)` is something you are looking after, but without code example that explains what are you trying to achieve there is nothing I can do.

Comment: @JustMe well I can show you the code but its quite long and there are pictures in it

Comment: @FredrikNilsson That's pretty much what a minimal example is for. But yeah, do check the `on_touch_up` in the [Widget's documentation](https://kivy.org/docs/api-kivy.uix.widget.html).